# La expresión regular valida una IP incorrecta porque coincide con sólo una parte de ésta

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

Tengo la siguiente expresión regular:

```
(([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])\.){3}([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])|(localhost)
```

Mi intención es que valide tanto una IP como la palabra `localhost`.

El problema está en que, por ejemplo, me traga `256.255.255.255`.

Lo estoy probando en esta página http://www.regexr.com/

- introduciendo `255.255.255.255`, me coge como válido `255.255.255.2`
- y si introduzco `256.255.255.255`, me coge como válido `56.255.255.2`.

Ese es el código que uso para validar la expresión.

```
var hostExp = "(([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])\.){3}([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])|(localhost)";

function checkHost() {
   return $("#host").val().match(hostExp) ? true : false;
}
```

¿Alguien tiene idea de que tengo mal o que funciona mal?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Nada está funcionando mal. Tu expresión es correcta. Sólo hay que considerar un tema importante:

Las expresiones regulares intentan **coincidir con una subcadena en cualquier lugar del texto**.

Para exigirle que sólo pueda coincidir con el texto completo, se deben utilizar las [anclas](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#special-caret) `^` y `$`, que coinciden con el inicio y el final del string respectivamente.

```
var hostExp =  /^(([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])\.){3}([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])$|^(localhost)$/;

if (hostExp.test(texto)) {

}
```

---

Además, algunos puntos extra a tener en cuenta. Hay partes de tu expresión que no es necesario agrupar (tiene algunos paréntesis de más), y cuando uno agrupa, suele ser recomendable usar [grupos sin captura](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#Usando_par%C3%A9ntesis).

`(?:expresión)` es exactamente lo mismo que `(expresión)`, con el beneficio de que no utiliza memoria para capturar el texto que coincidió con ese subpatrón.

Aprovecho además para acortarla un poco.

```js
var texto = "255.255.255.255";

var hostExp = /^(?:(?:[1-9]?[0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])\.){3}(?:[1-9]?[0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])$|^localhost$/;

if (hostExp.test(texto)) {
    console.log("Coincide con " + texto);
}
```

- se siguió la intención del autor, de no aceptar números con 0 a la izquierda.

---

Alternativamente, si quisieras que coincida con una IP dentro de otro texto, podrías utilizar [límites de palabra completa](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#special-word-boundary): `\b`.

```
/\b(?:(?:[1-9]?[0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])\.){3}(?:[1-9]?[0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])\b|\blocalhost\b/
```

Ejemplo: 
https://regex101.com/r/6UEpy2/1

Comment: Añadiendo esos símbolos, no me coge ninguna parte de la cadena... Pd: gracias por la ayuda

Comment: Estoy intentando contra 255.255.255.255, contra 256.255.255.255 y contra localhost, y si pongo los símbolos no entiendo porque no funciona, de hecho en un principio los puse pero al no funcionar los quité....

Comment: Mariano, te edité la respuesta para cambiar "parentescos" por "parentesis". Estas desde el movil ? XD

Comment: Estoy empezando a pensar que sea cosa de la página en la que lo pruebo, porque es poner ^ y $ y no coger nada... @lois6b

Comment: Símbolos me refiero al ^ y el $

Comment: @G3l0 podés verlo funcionando en http://regexr.com/3g0ua

Comment: Vale muchas gracias, supongo entonces que el problema esté en que tenía demasiado texto de prueba.

Comment: Se me ha olvidado decir que lo he probado en mi aplicación y funciona a las mil maravillas, un saludo y gracias por la ayuda.

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que en la comprobación de los números primero tienes el patrón que busca números de un sólo dígito, luego el de dos y finalmente el de tres.

Si inviertes el orden te cogerá la IP completa:

```
 ((1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5]|[1-9][0-9]|[0-9])\.){3}(1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5]|[1-9][0-9]|[0-9])|(localhost)
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, esta es la expresión que mejores resultados parece dar, lo único el tema del 256 que me coge 56 como válido y no se me ocurre como podría capar eso

Comment: Pero sí para el resultado de la coincidencia. Que es el problema que estaba teniendo en realidad.
El problema que tenía era que con el valor 255 son valores válidos tanto el 2 como el 25 como el 255 y le estaba cogiendo el primero porque era el primer patrón que encontraba, cuando lo que quería era que en este caso cogiera el último.

Comment: No es así. Cuando un intento falla, el motor de expresiones regulares seguirá intentando con la siguiente opción dentro del patrón (en este caso, la siguiente alternancia). El problema que tenía no era con "255" sino con "256", ya que tomaba como válido una parte de la IP. O sea que coincidía con 2**56.255.255.255** (dejando el 2 del inicio por fuera de la coincidencia). Esto se resuelve anclando al regex, ya sea con `^` o con `\b`